# Is there any function blueprint / autocomplete functionality in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm looking for something that can basically blueprint a function in sublime text.

Example:
When coding in JavaScript, you can type `fun`, which then shows a popup.

[image]

Hitting enter on this will produce this function blueprint:

[image]

Very convenient, obviously. I'm looking for something that can do the exact same, but for custom functions. So for example, for this function:

```
function asynchFunction(callback) {
  // doStuff
  callback(arguments);
}
```

I would love to have the following blueprint come up when I type `asynchFunction` (or part of it) and hit enter on the popup:

```
asynchFunction(function(arguments) {

});
```

Does something like this exist for Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [snippet](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html). The one you're describing in your question is one that ships with Sublime in the default JavaScript package, but you can add your own as appropriate.

To set yourself up with something like what you mentioned, you can select `Tools > Developer > New Snippet...` from the menu to create a stub snippet, and then modify it accordingly.

For your example, the result would look something like this:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
asynchFunction(function(${1:arguments}) {
    ${0:// body...}
});
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>asyncFunction</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.js</scope>
    <description>Async Function</description>
</snippet>
```

The `tabTrigger` is the text that triggers the snippet, and is what appears as the first portion of the text in the auto-completion popup. The `description` is used in the popup as well to describe what the snippet is for, to give you some context.

The `scope` (here `source.js`) determines in what files the snippet is available. If you leave it out, the snippet will be available everywhere, so this sets it to only appear in JavaScript sources.

After you make your changes (if any), save the file in the location that Sublime will default to (your `User` package) with some descriptive name and the extension `sublime-snippet`, and you should be good to go.

Once the snippet is saved, it will automatically start appearing when necessary, including appearing in the Command Palette as a `Snippet:` command, including when you select `Tools > Snippet...` from the menu.

See the linked documentation above for more details on the body of the snippet itself, but in short:

- Items like `${1:text}` are `fields`; `text` is the default text of the field, and <kbd>Tab</kbd> skips between fields in numeric order, starting at `1`. Multiple items with the same field number can appear in the snippet; they'll all change at once while you're editing that field.
- The `${0}` field is special and indicates where the cursor should end up when you've gone through all of the fields. The default is the end of the snippet content if it's not present.
- Due to the above, the `$` character is special in the snippet body; if you want to insert a literal `$` character in the snippet, use `\$` instead.
- No matter how much you think it's not needed, don't remove the `![CDATA[` and  `]]>` text.